# how can I replace a color with another one in photoshop ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need a tool to replace all pixels having a specific color with another color..

So basically a brush that works only with pixel having a specific color.

thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to do this:

You can use the colour replacement brush:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/10.0/help.html?content=WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7600.html

You can use layers, double click on the background layer to make it 'layer 0'.

You could then select by colour (eyedropper the color to make it the current foreground color, then use Select > Color Range), setting fuzziness accordingly..

Then you can put this selection into a layer mask.

Now you can create a new layer, fill it with your desired colour and drag it below layer 0 to show through the holes created earlier.

Flatten the image if okay, otherwise you can edit the layer mask as desired.

Comment: That's a very interesting solution :)